# Superuser.com bug with pixel.quantserve.com?

Tags: support

I have noticed this for the past few days, Many SuperUser.com pages simply do not finish loading.

[image]

I refreshed the page ten times, once it was stuck on "Waiting for www.gravitar.com...", but I cannot recreate that, all the other times it says "Transferring data from pixel.quantserve.com..." and hangs on that.

I just tried it at my neighbours house and on another computer and got the same result, but only in Firefox, IE seems to load just fine (or at least, doesn't show that it is waiting for/loading anything else).

Nothing has changed here and I was wondering if anyone else is getting similar results?

Comment: `norepo` for me. FF3.6

Comment: :( That isn't what I wanted to hear! I didn't post this a few days ago thinking it was just me... When I got the same results at neighbours, I posted... No idea what it is then.

Answer (score 1):

I periodically see issues with even Google Analytics, but they tend to be intermittent in nature.

Comment: +1 Thanks... Is it just Superuser.com that uses quantserv? My machine is still doing it this morning, so it has been several days now it has been doing this.

Comment: @wil nope they all use the same exact markup, only the question databases and per-site settings (logo, strings, etc) are different

Comment: Well, now it is a real mystery to me - Superuser.com still isn't fully loading and all the other sites are fine.

Comment: Well, I had this for a few weeks but it seems to of sorted itself out, no idea why and actually forgot all about it... Oh well!